# VPN and proxy together

Tags: vpn, proxy

We need to connect two site together to use a web application. we have set up reverse and forward proxy already. Shall we set up site-to-site VPN also for security measure? Is it typical?

Answer (score 0):

If these are fixed sites, I would surely use a site-to-site VPN for convenience and security.

With a good site-to-site VPN some attacks are impossible or much harder.

Comment: Thank so much. the sites are fixed, but can't reverse proxy act for security?